# I see my monero block was processed on blockchain but not showing up in wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

First time post , I appreciate your patience in advance.

I bought monero on Kraken via my account. Once that was processed I then sent my monero to the Address generated from my GUI Wallet (windows os).

This was well over 7 hours ago and I still dont see my balance in the GUI yet Kraken states that the monero was sent succesfully.

I have taken a look at the block which was 1489964. I see my transaction within the block as expected.

Now I want to state I am using a local node for the GUI and that has not yet completed to 100% synch from what I can gather. So I assume once I am synched w/ my block in the blockchain I should be good moving forward.

If I do indeed see my transaction showing up within the block id/blockchain  should I be less concerned about having lost the money ? That is my primary concern, that the money is lost somehow and wont show up,

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Use that ^ guide to resolve your issue.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE - Thank you for taking the time to answer, I want you to know I sincerely appreciate it . I have dabbled in BTC and ETH, and I would like to say I am very excited to be participating in the Monero world, the technology + potential is very exciting to me. 

Having said that I have used https://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html to check my txn from Kraken to my GUI wallet address. After inputting the txn hash, private view key and public address I indeed see 
'This address owns output 1 with pubkey '***' for an amount 'xyz' , 
Total received : 'xyz'

'xyz' = amount sent from Kraken

Comment: If that checks out, please proceed with the aforementioned guide to resolve your issue.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE - Thank you, currently still downloading the blockchain on a local node, which is literally taking days. Still not yet at my txn block yet. Having said that, I *think* I can point my GUI Wallet to a remote node to confirm my wallet funds, correct? If so, then I also assume that wont negatively effect my local node / daemon from continuing to download the blockchain while I simultaneously use the remote node to simply confirm my wallet / address balance in the GUI? Or, would I be able to run the command line wallet instead? Looking for ways to confirm wallet balance b4 download done

Comment: Are you syncing the blockchain to the default directory? If so, I can give you specific steps for doing this.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE I am using the default settings, so I would assume the default directory is the sync location on my PC. I would love to hear any input you may have, appreciated in advance.

Comment: I wrote some steps for you here: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/20vhsFOZSjwLm~1j~5MSHQ. Let me know if you incur any issues.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE thank you for these instructions. I am in the process of synching the blockchain from the aforementioned remote node whilst monerod does a full local sync in the background. I will update once fully synched w/ remote node. Tx again. Much appreciated.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE I can report that after a full synch on remote node the wallet balance has been updated correctly. I will revert to local node once the monerod fully synchs w/ bchain. thank you very very much for your time and effort towards educating me on monero use. community participation and involvement is what excites me greatly about monero. hopefully one day i can pay it forward. kindest regards.

Comment: You're welcome and good to hear you were able to see your balance whilst your local node is syncing in the background :)